# Is it possible and allowed for MFP App to call Web Services without Adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible and allowable for MFP application to call web services directly without using adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's called making standard AJAX calls. Which means these calls will not benefit the features that are possible through MobileFirst (such as security, etc).

Comment: I see. So it will be a very normal AJAX calls? And out of MFP?

Comment: That is correct. Of course, if your backend is behind MFP then you won't be able to reach it because it is protected by MFP and AJAX calls will not be able to handle that. Adapters will.